# Reverting back text()

Tags: jquery, revert

Currently I am trying the following:

1. By pressing button 'edit' it is changing all text within class .harms with a certain text.
2. By pressing button 'revert' it should return the oldcontent to it's original state.

Now I have two harms with both a unique text which is both being translated into something else. Now when I revert back to original text it is displaying both harms in one harm. You can see my Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/qhqyro12/1/

```
<div>
  <p class="harms">This is a first test</p>
  <p id="test" class="harms">This is a second test</p>
  <a id="edit">edit</a>
  <a id="revert">revert</a>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
    var myOldContent = $(".harms").text();

    $('#edit').click(function() {
        $('.harms').text('I want this to revert back to original state.');
    });

    $('#revert').click(function() {
        $(".harms").text(myOldContent);
    });
});
```

How can I make sure the correct string is placed back in the correct .harms
Thanks.

Comment: So when you click `.edit` which `.harms` element should be affected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize `jQuery.data()` to store original content of every `harms`.
After you click `edit` your original data is stored in data, and when you click `revert`, its value is restored.

```js
// Implementation:
var originalContentDataAttributeName = "originalContent";

function setRevertableText($el, text) {
  $el.data(originalContentDataAttributeName, $el.text());
  $el.text(text);  
}

function revertText($el) {
  // You may want to check for data attribute existence here
  $el.text($el.data(originalContentDataAttributeName));
  $el.removeData(originalContentDataAttributeName);
}

// Usage:
$("#edit").click(function() {
  $(".harms").each(function() {
    setRevertableText($(this), "I want this to revert back to original state.");
  });
});

$("#revert").click(function() {
  $(".harms").each(function() {
    revertText($(this));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="harms">This is a first test</p>
  <p id="test" class="harms">This is a second test</p>
  <a id="edit">edit</a>
  <a id="revert">revert</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev, your answer helped me out a lot and works great.

Answer (score 1):

You should save your old text first before editing:

```
$(function() {
  var myOldContent;

  $('#edit').click(function() {
    myOldContent = $('.harms').text();
    $('.harms').text('I want this to revert back to original state.');
  });

  $('#revert').click(function() {
    $(".harms").text(myOldContent);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#edit').click(function(){
  $('.hurms').each(function(i, elem){
    elem = $(elem);
    elem.attr('prev-content', elem.text());
    elem.text('you template text');
  });
});

$('#revert').click(function(){
  $('.hurms').each(function(i, elem){
    elem = $(elem);
    elem.text(elem.attr('prev-content'));
  });
});
```

this should work

Answer (score 0):

You can store the old value in [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/). And then retrieve it again when you click revert.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#edit').click(function() {
      $('.harms').each(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        // Store the current text in data old.
        $this.data('old', $this.text());
        // Set the new text.
        $this.text('I want this to revert back to original state.');
      });
        
    });

    $('#revert').click(function() {
      $('.harms').each(function(value, index){
        $this = $(this);
        // Fetch the old text from data.
        var old = $this.data('old');
        // Set the text on the element.
        $this.text(old);
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="harms">This is a first test</p>
  <p id="test" class="harms">This is a second test</p>
  <a id="edit">edit</a>
  <a id="revert">revert</a>
</div>
```